# Batch file for loop dynamic variables from file without setlocal?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, global-variables

I have a simple ini file... really just a key=value file that I want to use to set as variables for my script.

My ini file:

```
DATABASE=snoopy
```

My Batch file code

```
@echo off
SET DATABASE=woodstock

FOR /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a in ('C:\mycfg.ini') do (
    echo a=%%a
    echo b=%%b
    pause
    SET %%a=%%b
    ECHO DATABASE=%DATABASE%
)
```

The echo a and b are correct, it shows

```
a=DATABASE
b=snoopy
```

But at the end when I echo %DATABASE% after calling the SET %%a=%%b 
It still shows

```
DATABASE=woodstock
```

If I use delayed expansion, it works but only locally. I need it to overwrite the global so I don't see why this shouldn't work.

Comment: Would you explain what you mean by `local` versus `global`?  Is `local` the current CMD window and `global` the set of environment variables that are set when you open a new CMD window from the *Start Menu* (e.g., all future CMD windows)?  BTW - You won't be able to modify other already open CMD windows.

Comment: I mean using SetLocal/EndLocal.. Actually thinking about it, I am using SetLocal before the for loop.. maybe I should be using it at the top of the file. I'll try that

Comment: When you enabled delayed expansion, did you change your echo to use the delayed-expansion operator?  `ECHO DATABASE=!DATABASE!`

Answer (score 0):

Well, no need to do anything to make it work.

It works.

Your problem is that when the `for` block (all the lines in parenthesis in your code) are read, variables are replaced with their values, so the line `echo %DATABASE%` is converted in `echo woodstock`. BUT the variable hold the correct value, changed inside the `for` loop. Try to place the echo outside of the for and see what the value is.

Delayed expansion is needed when a variable is changed inside a block and it is necesary to access the changed value inside the same block.

Comment: Yes, I see now.. I moved setlocal enabledelayedexpansion to the top of my file and worked it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it now..
Had to enable delayed expansion at the top of the file rather than just on the subroutine call. Then set the %%a and %%b to delayed variables and set them equal to eachother and that worked. Final code:

```
@echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

SET DATABASE=woodstock

FOR /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a in ('C:\mycfg.ini') do (
   set tmpA=%%a
   set tmpB=%%b
   SET !tmpA!=!tmpB!
)
ECHO DATABASE=%DATABASE%
```

And that changes it to "snoopy"

Thanks all!

Comment: Too much complication. `for .... do ( set "%%a=%%b" )` as initial code had, works with no problem and without `setlocal`. As said, changes are visible outside the for loop. Delayed expansion is only necessary to see the changes inside the same loop where the variable changes its value.

Comment: ... or the even simpler: `for /f "delims=" %%a in (C:\mycfg.ini) do set "%%a"`

Comment: Aacini!! that's it! perfect. Didn't realize you could do `SET "VAR=VALUE"` like that